# Dictionary "Key" and "Value" properties names aren't being camel-case serialized

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

When serializing a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, this is the JSON I am obtaining:

```
[
    {
        "Key": "Mineplex",
        "Value": "ULTRA"
    }
]
```

However, I'd like it to be `key` instead of `Key`, and `value` instead of `Value`.

I am already using `JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`.

How can I do?

Comment: where did you set the option?

Comment: @phonemyatt `new JsonSerializerOptions(){ PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase }` on serialization

Comment: probably link to this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1197). can use keyvaluepair class instead?

Comment: Try creating your own `JsonConverter<KeyValuePair>` custom converter as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to).

Comment: .This link could help you. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31345

Comment: There is an open github issue [#1197](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1197) for that. I've added an answer with workaround below, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some workaround here, use [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) method to create a new collection of anonymous objects with required properties names

```cs
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Mineplex", "ULTRA")
};
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list.Select(l => new { key = l.Key, value = l.Value }));
```

You'll get the following JSON `[{"key":"Mineplex","value":"ULTRA"}]`

You can also wait until GitHub issue [#1197](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1197) will be fixed to get an expected behavior

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use the following class?

```cs
public class JsonLowercaseKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{
    public JsonLowercaseKeyValuePair(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("key")]
    public TKey Key { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
List<JsonLowercaseKeyValuePair<string, string>>
```

Comment: Not satisfied by this answer, but I guess I'll use it while the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1197) gets fixed.

Comment: you should follow the issue on github. once it's fixed you can use back what you desire

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newtonsoft in this way:

```
DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    {
        ProcessDictionaryKeys = true
    }
};

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = contractResolver,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};

var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionaryListData, settings);
```

Comment: OP is using `System.Text.Json` API